# Transform a continued fraction to an ordinary fraction

Tags: simplifying-expressions, continued-fractions

I need to calculate (tranform to a 1-level fraction) the following continued fraction:

```
expr = 1/(x - a1 - 
    b1^2/(x - a2 - 
       b2^2/(x - a3 - 
          b3^2/(x - a4 - 
             b4^2/(x - a5 - 
                b5^2/(x - a6 - 
                   b6^2/(x - a7 - b7^2/(x - a8 - b8^2/(x - a9)))))))))
```

Wolfram Alpha calls it an "Alternative form", but WA has been stuck for so long. I know nothing about Mathematica's syntax (I mostly use Python). Can you please help me?

Comment: Try `Together` or `Apart`

Comment: Don't use underscore in varaible names!

Comment: Is this supposed to be a finite continued fraction, or an inifinite one? Do you know the values of the coefficients `a1, b1, a2, b2, ...`?

Comment: What @DanielHuber suggested was `Together[expr]` if you want it as a giant fraction of 985 terms over 2378 terms.  With general coefficients `Apart` will give you only one fraction.